# Kubernetes ( Azure VM ) change node ip

Tags: kubernetes

The internal IP address of a Kubernetes single node has changed and now kubelet isn’t starting correctly anymore.

Therefore I’ve started changing the configuration of the follwoing files:

/.kube/config
/etc/kubernetes/*.conf

I’ve added the new ip address to these files.
After this step, I got the error saying that the X509 certificate is not valid for the new ip.

In order to solve this issue, I’ve done the following steps:

1. Stop kubelet and delete all old cert files from /etc/kubernetes/pki and /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
2. kubeadm init phase certs adminserver —adminserver-advertise-address  —adminserver-cert-extra-sans
3. kubeadm init phase certs adminserver-kubelet-client
4. kubeadm init phase certs front-proxy-ca
5. kubeadm init phase certs front-proxy-client
6. kubeadm init phase certs apiserver-etcd-client
7. kubeadm init phase certs etcd-ca
8. kubeadm init phase certs etcd-healthcheck-client
9. kubeadm init phase certs etcd-peer
10. kubeadm init phase certs etcd-server
11. kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all —apiserver-advertise-address
12. kubeadm init phase certs renew all
13. copied /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf to ~/.kube and renamed it to config
14. kubeadm init phase kubelet-start

The problem is that I still get an error saying that the connection to the new IP was refused. I belive it’s due to a wrong certificate, but the apiserver.crt file seems correct if I compare it to the original certificate.

I tried the same approape on a machine which is running locally and I got kubelet to start correctly and kubectl to work again.
Can anyone point me to what I’m doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use? How exactly did you deploy your cluster? Did you see [this article](https://newbedev.com/invalid-x509-certificate-for-kubernetes-master)?

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your comments. I found the reason for the issue. After changing the files in /etc/kubernetes/manifests all worked fine. The system is back up and running.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update the manifest files located under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` and ensure that the new host IP is set there as well.